# Should I insist on being a functional programmer on Python?

Tags: software-development

Just some background: I was kind a cowboy coder for a long time, then I got a job at a startup company as a developer.

I learned a lot there, specially about good practices on programming. However, the company had a highly functional programming mindset, although we were developing in Python. While it did work, I thought it was sort of a work around and using the language from a different purpose from what it looks more capable of doing. One of the issues I had with it was the extra libraries we had to use (returns and pyrsistent) exclusively to achieve this and how many capabilities of classes we lost, while not having something to put in its place (like rust has trait, for instance).

I am now working at a different company, and I have much more freedom to decide what programming style I will use, although I am still limited to the language Python.

So, I would like to know the opinion of this community: do you think I should continue using Python adapted to a functional programming style, which is the one that I know the best practices, in general; or should I learn how to have good programming practices in a more "pythonic" way? How would I go about doing it?

Edit:  A "cowboy coder" is slang for someone who does not have a solid knowledge on good practices when coding, and just goes for it with the mentality of "if it works, it works", not thinking about maintainability, adaptability to future requirements, etc

Comment: What does "**Cowboy Coder**" mean ?

Comment: @Job_September_2020 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowboy_coding.  Basically it means running everything with no systems by the seat of your pants.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python was not designed as a functional programming language (as evidenced from the fact that you need to use third party libraries to get some of the missing functionality). And this means that most Python developers do not write using a functional programming style (and may not even be familiar with it).

By writing Python code in an unusual style, you're going to make it harder for other Python developers to read, understand and maintain. And while you might be a solo developer at the moment (it's not clear from your question), that probably won't always be the case - either because you become part of a larger team, or you get replaced by someone.

So you need to think about not just what you prefer, but what is better *for the business*. Do the benefits *for the business* of you writing code in that style outweigh the costs?

- Can you justify why it's worth using the third party libraries (with the potential licensing and dependency management costs) because you want to write code in a specific style?
- Are you going to be sufficiently more productive that it's worth writing code that'll be harder for the next developer to maintain?
- If the company hires another Python program who hasn't done functional programming, how long is it going to take you to train them?

It's also worth considering that if you only know how to write functional Python, you're going to be limiting your options for jobs going forward. If you join an existing development team or project, you're not going to be able to tell them all to convert to your preferred style: so learning how to do things the Pythonic way will open doors for you and make your life easier in future.